# Merging partial/subset yaml into one

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to find a good approach to merge a partial (or subset) of an existing YAML into the original one.

For example, I have the following YAML:

```yaml
foo: &foo
  bar: 1

baz:
  <<: *foo
  qux: 1
```

Now, I also have a subset of this YAML, as a raw text:

```yaml
baz:
  <<: *foo
  qux: 2
```

And I'd like to see how I can replace the part in the existing YAML with the subset, so the result would be:

```yaml
foo: &foo
  bar: 1

baz:
  <<: *foo
  qux: 2
```

Up until now I used `ruamel.yaml`, which is great, but I'm not sure it has this capability as it's a bit tricky - when I try to `load` the subset it throws that `foo` alias is undefined (... obviously). Moreover, if I'd be able to load it (somehow) I'm still not sure how to replace the entire thing and keep it with the same formatting.

The workaround that I did is pretty risky - I read the file, when I find the key that I want to update I simply insert the updated version above it and use `allow_duplicate_keys = True` in order to load the YAML & dump it later on. After the insert it looks like:

```yaml
foo: &foo
  bar: 1

baz:
  <<: *foo
  qux: 2

baz:
  <<: *foo
  qux: 1
```

And because I set `allow_duplicate_keys = True`, the last `baz` is ignored.

Any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: So you always have `&foo`, if you also always have `<<: *foo` in your subset, you can leave that out of the, invalid YAML, subset, which would make it valid. The only thing you need to do then is do a recursive merge (or one at least one deep, depending on your subset), of the data loaded from the original and from the subset. It is possible to preserve the anchors from a previous load, but of course that doesn't make much sense if you don't merge the data from the two loads in some way.

Comment: The subset does not contain `&foo` (yes, it's invalid YAML indeed), hence I cannot load it (or I'm missing something?):/ btw, I used a bad terminology - I want to replace it completely (not merge it).